# Swagger c# DataAnnotations: Placeholder in Parameter Fields

Tags: c#, .net, swagger, swagger-ui, data-annotations

Instead of prefilling with DefaultValue, is there a way to add placeholder values to the documentation?

Edit: the following would produce

```
public ActionResult TestGet(
    [DefaultValue("hello world")]
    string test) => Ok();
```

[image]
But it will also prefill with that test when selecting 'try it out'.
I want to be able to give a description in place of the grey text  that won't appear once being typed out (placeholder text). This is something that can be done in HTML input components.

Comment: you have to share some code to get help

Comment: Apologies, is that clearer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of xml comments:

Step 1 : add xml comments to your methods like this. remove default value

```
    /// <summary>
    /// TestGet
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="test">Enter your input here</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("TestGet")]
    public ActionResult TestGet(string test) => Ok();
```

Step 2: Enable document generation in project setting.

[image]

Step 3: tell swagger to include xml comments.

```
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.IncludeXmlComments(Path.Combine(
                    Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location),
                    $"WebApplication1.xml"));
});
```

Result:
you can use description to write whatever you want.

[image]

Comment: It's not perfect as it's not placeholder text but it's pretty darn good! Thanks :)